# Should questions which cannot be answered without follow up from OP, but OP never follows up, be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, unanswered-questions, vote-to-close

I find many questions in this site where OP states about serious condition of his/her pet and asks for advice.

Incidentally, no advice is possible without more information. So OP is requested for more information. But OP never follows up and that question remains unanswered for a long time for the obvious reason that the question cannot be answered with the information that had been initially provided by OP.

In such circumstances, should that question be closed?

If not, why?

If yes, then what reason should be chosen while casting close vote?

Comment: Can you include a link to a good example of this type of question?

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19878/kitten-acting-in-a-strange-manner-suddenly-and-getting-scared-for-no-reason

Answer (score 4):

If it is not a duplicate:

- You can vote to close with "Unclear what you are asking" this is the best option.  When it gets 5 close votes it will be closed.

If you don't have enough rep to cast close votes you can flag it as "should be closed" > "Unclear what you are asking"

If it is a duplicate:

- Flag as a duplicate.  It is always good to check for possible duplicates.

If it might be a duplicate:

- Flag as a duplicate.  If the OP comes back with more info showing it is not a duplicate, we can reopen it. Often, the possible duplicate will have the answer they are looking for, they will see the duplicate flag when (if) the come back and link to the answer they need.

Moderator votes are binding, so we normally try to let the community complete the close votes unless it is really clear.  Often, mods will wait until there are 3 or 4 existing votes before casting a vote, so they will only count as one or two.

Comment: One little nitpick. Moderator vote doesn't *count* as 4 or 5, moderator vote is considered *binding*, which means if the moderator casts a close vote, the question gets closed immediately *and* a moderator cannot "retract" their close vote. The same goes for reopen votes. I understand your statement kinda implies the same thing and this is anyway, not the main topic of the question, but I thought it could be a bit confusing to people not familiar with the site, so decided to post this comment here.

Comment: @Thanos No one can retract a vote after it is closed, you can only cast re-open votes. Related [The word binding is a little bit misleading, since posts closed by a moderator can be reopened by the community.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124098/217279)